# Zend Framework 2 , how to Cache the ACL for better Performance

Tags: caching, zend-framework2, memcached, acl

I am using `XML` to store my ACL configs, and extended the `Zend ACL` library to parse the ROLES & Resources, and its working great.

Below is my `ACL.XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<permissions>
    <roles>
        <role name="guest" />
        <role name="user" inherits="guest" />
        <role name="admin" inherits="user" />
    </roles>
    <resources>
        <module name="account" allow="user">
            <controller name="account\controller\account" allow="user">
                <action name="login" deny="admin" />
            </controller>
        </module>
         <module name="album" allow="user">
            <controller name="album\controller\album" allow="user">
                <action name="index" allow="user" />
                <action name="add" allow="admin" />
            </controller>
        </module>
        <module name="application" allow="user">
            <controller name="application\controller\index" allow="user">
                <action name="index" allow="user" />
            </controller>
        </module>
    </resources>
</permissions>
```

And my `Module.php` code that is currently called via `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH` event,

```
    $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

    $configCache    = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__.'/config/acl.xml');

    $serviceManager->get('memcache')->setItem('cacheXml', $configCache);

    //print_r($serviceManager->get('memcache')->getItem('cacheXml'));

    $this->_acl     = $serviceManager->get('Acl');

    $this->_acl->initAcl($configCache);

    if (! $this->_acl->_isAllowed('user', $event->getRouteMatch())) {
                $url = $event->getRouter()->assemble(array('action' => 'index'), array('name' => 'application'));
                $response = $event->getResponse();
                $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
                $response->setStatusCode(302);
                $response->sendHeaders();
                exit;
   } else {
       echo 'Access granted :) ';
   }
```

How can I CACHE my ACL class ( from service manager ) or by any other means so that the piece of code becomes more persistent and optimized. I am using `memcache` for my `caching`.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to create a ZendAclFactory and from there build an instance or return from cache.

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Acl;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl as ZendAcl;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource;
use Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole as Role;

class ZendAclFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    private $cache;

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->cache = $serviceLocator->get('MyCache');
        $service = $this->cache->getItem('acl');
        if (!empty($service)) {
            $service = unserialize($service);
            return $service;
        }

        $service = new ZendAcl();
        //initialize you acl here..

        $this->cache->addItem('acl', serialize($service));
        return $service;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jean will look into it, btw I am now caching the ACL in memcache and its working fine, Ill also post my approach . Ill try yours too